# How can I enforce so Notepad++ uses UTF-8 every time I create a new file?

Tags: notepad++, character-encoding, utf-8

I want to use the character encoding UTF-8 (without BOM) on my files. I can change the encoding from the "Format" menu, but it is reset every time I create a new file or open a file.

How can I do so Notepad++ uses UTF-8 (without BOM) as default encoding?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to

`Settings -> Preferences -> New Document/ Open Save Directory`

and then in

`New Document -> Encoding` check  `UTF8 without BOM`

You might also want to tick "Apply to opened ANSI files":

[image: screenshot notepad settings]

Answer (score 3):

Just bumping once again here at superuser

**Step 1:
Settings -> Preferences -> New Document ->[Encodng] UTF-8 without BOM (check Apply to opened ANSI files)**

but any how it hadn't solved mine , i searched out and found that its a bug!

```
Notepad++ v6.4.5 bug fixes:

1.Fix a crash issue while there's missing tag in functionList.xml. 

2.Fix UTF-8 (w/o BOM) detection bug.
```

**Step 2: That's all have an update to >= v6.4.5 and follow Step 1**